# Set BUSD transaction value in web3 ETH send transaction

Tags: web3js, metamask, meta-transactions

I followed the instructions on [Binance docs](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/BEP20.html), using `Web3js` to create a transaction.

I want to create a BUSD transaction on web3 using `metamask`

```
  try {
        const transactionHash = ethereum.request({
            
            method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
            params: [
            {
                to: 'addr',
                from: ethereum.selectedAddress,
                value: Web3.utils.toWei(amount), //set or convert value to BUSD
                chainId: 56
            },
            ],
        });
        console.log(transactionHash);
        //
        } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get price BNB and set amount is busd = (amount_busd * price_bnb)